# Does Identity Server 4 allow Creation of Users via an External API?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid, identityserver4

Most OPEN ID providers have an external API that allows you to add Users. See this page for Okta as an example -
https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users

For Identity Server 4, it seems like they do not expose an external API that allows you to create new users. Even the "Admin UI" through which Users can be added seems to be paid option.

Identity Server Documentation -
https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: IS4 is highly extensible, so the answer is yes. But not out of the box, you'll have to add it yourself. You don't have to write all code, you can use the UserManager, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pre-built functionality for this in Identity Server 4. To perform any user-related operations in Identity Server 4, custom components must be registered with ASP.NET Core's new dependency injection system. To establish an endpoint for creating users I would make an endpoint that creates users in the designated database for authentication (in the same way you did things before Identity Server).